# Email attachments - 7Bit enconding

Tags: email, encoding, smtp

I am implementing a custom application (in .net 4.0) which sends email with attachments . I tried to encode attachments with Base64 however it makes the message bigger (and our smtp server has message size limits). That's why I am thinking if 7Bit could resolve my problem. What are the pros and cons of sending email attachments using 7Bit encoding ?

Comment: What exactly does "7Bit encoding" mean to you in this context? It's clear that you don't see it the way I do, which is that you use Base64 encoding on your binary data to achieve a 7-bit data stream to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), it will use the most efficient encoding (size-wise) for sending via SMTP depending on what extensions the SMTP server supports.

Just set the encoding for all (binary) MimePart attachments to `ContentEncoding.Binary` and SmtpClient.Send() will figure out the most efficient encoding to use (i.e. if the server supports BINARYMIME, then it will send w/o encoding. If it supports 8BITMIME, it will send as 8bit as long as the attachment has no null bytes). If you set it to something else, though, it will use that encoding instead.